# Disallow usage of authorize attribute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

Let's say I created `CustomAuthorizeAttribute` that inherits from `AuthorizeAttribute` in `System.Web.Http` namespace.

It would be nice if there was, compile-time protection against using `Authorize` attribute and message to use `CustomAuthorize` instead. I know there's `ObsoleteAttribute` that can result in compile-time error, can we implement something like this?

Comment: You can try to create your [Roslyn analyzer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt162308.aspx)

Comment: You might want to have a look into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261685/attribute-to-generate-compilation-error-on-method-call) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843361/custom-attribute-that-can-generate-compile-time-error)